# Issues with version 17.0.0. google play warning - phone auth with play integrity api

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I got this warning when I was update my app on Playstore.

> Your latest production release (8 (2.0.7)) contains SDK issues
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.0
> This SDK version has a note from the SDK developer. Here's what the SDK developer told us:
>
> The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

Flutter phone authentication not working perfectly-  since safety net device verification is remove from the project. (Go to reCAPTCHA page)

my try :
add this to app level build gradle file

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0'
```

But it not worked. What I can do for fix this issue.
I'm using

```
firebase_auth: ^4.2.2
```

I got more details from-
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3890#issuecomment-1488368740

> Good news, everyone!
> We have just released Firebase Auth 21.2.0 (BoM 31.4.0) which adds support for Play Integrity in phone auth.
> We recommend that you migrate to it as soon as possible (just need to update the version in the Gradle file, no breaking changes in code).

Firebase phone auth will now attempt a Play Integrity verification and fallback to SafetyNet or reCAPTCHA if that fails. See more details in the docs.

Therefore, I tried above my try. But, It not worked

Comment: did you resolve it? i got the exact same problem